# support widget GridLayout error inflating

Tags: java, android, xml

For some reason when debugging my application on older devices (api 23, api 19) I get an error when I try to inflate the ViewHolder for my `RecycleView`'s children.

I've tried the following:

- Cleaning the project
- Rebuilding it
- Invalidating caches and restarting

I can't find the source of the issue:

Error log:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
```

Dependancies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0-rc1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.0'
    // Room (use 1.1.0-alpha3 for latest alpha)
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    // Paging
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha6'
    // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.0'
    // Test helpers for Room
    testImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0'
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView rowTitle = null;
    private TextView rowContent = null;
    private ImageView rowImage = null;

    private TextView deleteText = null;
    private TextView completeText = null;

    private DataCommunication mData = null;
    private GlobalLists associatedItem = null;
    private GridLayout background = null;
    private GridLayout foreground = null;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.mData = (DataCommunication)itemView.getContext();

        this.background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.backRow);
        this.foreground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foreRow);

        this.rowTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
        this.rowContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowContent);

        this.deleteText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteText);
        this.completeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.completeText);

        this.rowImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowImage);

        this.foreground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ViewHolder", "Clicked!");
                if (associatedItem != null)
                {
                    mData.setItemTitle(associatedItem.getTitle());
                    if(rowContent.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                        mData.setFullContents(associatedItem.getContents());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setRowTitle(String title) {
        if (title != null) {
            this.rowTitle.setText(title);
        }
    }

    public void setRowContent(String content) {
        if (content != null && content.length() > 0) {
            this.rowContent.setText(content);
        } else {
            this.rowContent.setText("");
        }
    }

    public void setAssociatedItem(GlobalLists item){
        this.associatedItem = item;
    }

    public TextView getDeleteText() {
        return this.deleteText;
    }

    public TextView getCompleteText() {
        return this.completeText;
    }

    public GridLayout getForeground() {
        return this.foreground;
    }

    public GridLayout getBackground() {
        return this.background;
    }

}




import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
//other imports

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView rowTitle = null;
    private TextView rowContent = null;
    private ImageView rowImage = null;

    private TextView deleteText = null;
    private TextView completeText = null;

    private DataCommunication mData = null;
    private GlobalLists associatedItem = null;
    private GridLayout background = null;
    private GridLayout foreground = null;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.mData = (DataCommunication)itemView.getContext();

        this.background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.backRow);
        this.foreground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foreRow);

        this.rowTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
        this.rowContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowContent);

        this.deleteText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteText);
        this.completeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.completeText);

        this.rowImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowImage);

        this.foreground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ViewHolder", "Clicked!");
                if (associatedItem != null)
                {
                    mData.setItemTitle(associatedItem.getTitle());
                    if(rowContent.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                        mData.setFullContents(associatedItem.getContents());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setRowTitle(String title) {
        if (title != null) {
            this.rowTitle.setText(title);
        }
    }

    public void setRowContent(String content) {
        if (content != null && content.length() > 0) {
            this.rowContent.setText(content);
        } else {
            this.rowContent.setText("");
        }
    }

    public void setAssociatedItem(GlobalLists item){
        this.associatedItem = item;
    }

    public TextView getDeleteText() {
        return this.deleteText;
    }

    public TextView getCompleteText() {
        return this.completeText;
    }

    public GridLayout getForeground() {
        return this.foreground;
    }

    public GridLayout getBackground() {
        return this.background;
    }

}
```

CustomRow (ViewHolder Layout File) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        app:useDefaultMargins="true"
        app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        app:rowCount="1"
        app:columnCount="3"
        android:id="@+id/backRow"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rounded_rectangle_accent"
        app:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deleteText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/deleteTask"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/completeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/completeTask"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>



    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/foreRow"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        app:rowCount="2"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rounded_rectangle"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info_outline"
            app:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_gravity="start"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_gravity="start"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>




</FrameLayout>
```

**Edit** This appears to be occuring mostly when debugging on hardware devices such as the LG G4 and emulators using API 19, Sometimes the gridlayout through an error or my viewpager throws an error..?

I've included my main_activity.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.lab1.ac01220.bloomv2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_backing"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: @Selvin I thought the android.support libraries were specifically to retain backwards compatability for older devices?

Comment: @Selvin ahh android.widget

Comment: @Selvin will my dependancies change?

Comment: try to remove `implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.0'` and replace all `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` with `android.widget.GridLayout` ... also you should replace `app:layout_column` and other GridLayout attributes to `android:layout_column`

Comment: @Selvin unfortunately no luck